# Is there a way to connect a social media feed to my page in Sitecore 9?

Tags: social-connected

I have been searching for a method to connect social media accounts within sitecore 9, my search so far has resulted in finding "social connect", but that apparently only works up to Sitecore 8.

My question is : is there any module available in Sitecore 9 now that can have the same functionality as Sitecore Connect? i.e. connect my site to social media feeds, or embed something like tweets in my web page created by sitecore 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no OOTB for Sitecore 9. You can:

1. Build these components and functionality as components for your client. Add General Link field where content editors need to specify link to embedded content e.g. 
   https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines and component will render HTML around to make it nicer
2. Use HTML code component of Sitecore SXA 1.7 module together with twitter or any other social network widget for teitter for instance use HTML code from here https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines

Comment: The solution you've provided is kind of the opposite of what i'm going for :  I'd like to find a way to display, say, certain tweets embedded from twitter into my Sitecore page, I believe the workaround you have provided on the blog gives me the ability to share my content from sitecore **to** a social media network, such as twitter/facebook, and i'm looking for the opposite :D

Comment: I have updated second option in my answer. I have misread question :) Sorry

Comment: great! thank you for your help! I've also found out there's a "twitter" component in SXA that can be used for the same purpose, but it only works on twitter, we need to follow the steps in this link https://learningsitecorecms.blogspot.com.eg/2017/08/how-to-use-twitter-in-sitecore.html and it'll work, if you could add that to your answer i think it might be helpful to other people :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for something like 'Stackla' which has an integration to Sitecore. It allows you to curate content from various social feeds and then embed it into your Sitecore site:

- https://www.sitecore.com/products/sitecore-experience-platform/cross-channel-delivery/stackla-user-generated-content-connector

If you are looking for Social login functionality, you can accomplish that now using Federated Authentication. There is an example of how to do so with Facebook within the Habitat v9 branch on GitHub:

- https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/habitat-federated-authentication-for-sitecore-9

Comment: I was mainly trying to look for a free source that could help me with this functionality, so stackla would be a bit of a problem. Thank you for your answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Stackla Dashboard allows you to create widgets and customise them as you wish, and then generates a code that you can embed into your website page, i.e. you can easily bring a user-generated content on social networks: Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, YouTube, Flickr and Pinterest to your website. You can be more clever when embedding Stackla widgets into Sitecore and specify dynamic parameters based on how you want to change Stackla settings and your variety of pages where you will place your module on.

You can have a look at my implementation of Stackla widgets in Sitecore released on GitHub [here](https://github.com/kate-orlova/stackla-widgets-in-sitecore), it can be helpful for you.